# Converting jquery "click" code to be used for php calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am relatively new to jquery/javascript, but I found great code (below) which allows for the use of modals.  A user will click a hyperlink with a class of "activate_modal," and this will open a modal on the screen.

It is working great, but I'd like to take the same concept and apply it to PHP calls.  For example, if during PHP verification of form submission someone fails to supply a required field, it will call to activate a modal.

It might be simple, but I can't figure it out!  All I want to do is have the same action occur that WOULD occur if the user were to click a link with the "activate_modal" class..

If anyone could help I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.activate_modal').click(function(){

//get the height and width of the page
var window_width = $(window).width();
var window_height = $(window).height();

//vertical and horizontal centering of modal window(s)
/*we will use each function so if we have more then 1 
modal window we center them all*/

$('.modal_window').each(function(){

    //get the height and width of the modal
    var modal_height = $(this).outerHeight();
    var modal_width = $(this).outerWidth();

    //calculate top and left offset needed for centering
    <!--var top = (window_height-modal_height)/2;-->
    var top = 100;
    var left = (window_width-modal_width)/2;

    //apply new top and left css values 
    $(this).css({'top' : top , 'left' : left});

});

 //get the id of the modal window stored in the name of the activating element       
 var modal_id = $(this).attr('name');

 //use the function to show it
 show_modal(modal_id);

});

$('.close_modal').click(function(){

//use the function to close it
close_modal();

});

});

//THE FUNCTIONS

function close_modal(){

//hide the mask
$('#mask').fadeOut(500);

//hide modal window(s)
$('.modal_window').fadeOut(500);

}

function show_modal(modal_id){

//set display to block and opacity to 0 so we can use fadeTo
$('#mask').css({ 'display' : 'block', opacity : 0});

//fade in the mask to opacity 0.8 
$('#mask').fadeTo(500,0.8);

 //show the modal window
$('#'+modal_id).fadeIn(500);

}
```

And here is an example of the hyperlink:

```
<a class='activate_modal' name='mymodal' href='#'>click here!</a>
```

Comment: Please research this yourself! I think the way to go is use `$.ajax()` to send the request to the PHP script and then check the response

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery AJAX call to submit your form and then on your PHP validate the information and send back the error messages.

Example:

```
$('#submit_btn').on('click', function(e) {
// call ajax
$.ajax({
    url: URL_TO_YOUR_PHP_VALIDATION_SCRIPT,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#formId').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
        // show loader
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // check status
        if(result.status == 'OK') {
            // show success message
        }
        else {
            // show error message
            // trigger modal popup
            modal.activate(); // the same way you trigger your modal
        }
    }
});
```

});